# Cakephp 3.~, Debugkit 3.~ isn't loading after update with composer

Tags: cakephp-3.x, cakephp-debug-kit

After i've updated cakephp 3.~ with composer the debugkit isn't it showing. And the webrowser keeps giving me the loading circle sign. I've tried "composer dump-autoload" and still no luck.

I'm developing local on "windows 10" with Wampserver 2.5.

Comment: btw this only occur on the windows machine. On the osx i've don't have this problem.

Comment: I've set the permission folders to writable in Windows 10, but first it didn't work for about a week. Suddenly it works again.